# DICOM -- DCMMKDIR -- File Name Max 8 Characters

Tags: dicom

I am writing an application which uses the DCM MKDIR, We save our images in little bigger name, but when I am trying to use the DCMMKDIR application, which is asking me to input file name max 8 characters.

Presently, I am planning to rename my Images starting from 1 to N. But remapping these images to known names(on the disk) will be bit difficult(I feel).

are there are any other methods/process to achieve the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The restriction of the filename to eight characters is derived from the DICOM Standard to ensure compatibility with applications that support e.g. only ISO 9660 as a file system for CDs.

About the naming you can have a look at the specifications the german CD Testat (http://www.dicom-cd.de/docs/DRG-RequirementsSpecification-2006.pdf). As a vendor you can be certified to conform to certain standards for interoperability of patient CDs which is currently the most common usage of DICOMDIRs.

The DICOMDIR file generated by DCMMKDIR is mainly a kind of index to tell an application, what DICOM files in a certain directory exist and this kind of file structure is usually more common for transfer media.

Answer (score 3):

It is very common to use subdirectories to circumvent the restriction on max 8 length filenames. For example, a file could be 20110331/183421/000001 which would identify it properly with date, time and index without exceeding the somewhat arcane filename limit.